# ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused macOS High Sierra

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the first part of this assignment you are going to implement an echo server which receives text message from client and sends it back to the client. (That’s why we call it echo server) When the server receives the text message from client, it capitalizes the odd characters of the text message. For example, when the client sends a text message of “hello elec 4120 student”, the server should return a text message of “HeLlO ElEc 4120 StUdEnT”.

With some hints from the instructor, my server code is as follow

```
from socket import *
serverPort = 12000

#create TCP welcoming socket
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind(('',serverPort))

#server begins listening for incoming TCP requests
serverSocket.listen(1)
print('The server is ready to receive')

while True:
#server waits on accept()
#for incoming requests, new socket created on return
      connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()

#read bytes from socket (but not address as in UDP)
      sentence = connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode()
      capitalizedSentence = sentence.upper()

#close connection to this client (but not welcoming socket)
      connectionSocket.send(capitalizedSentence.encode())
      connectionSocket.close()
```

and the client code is

```
from socket import *
serverPort = 12000
serverName = 'localhost'
#create TCP socket for server, remote port 12000
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.connect((serverName,serverPort))
sentence = raw_input('Input lowercase sentence:')

#No need to attach server name, port
clientSocket.send(sentence.encode())
modifiedSentence = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print ('From Server:', modifiedSentence.decode())
clientSocket.close()
```

and when I run the server code

```
'The server is ready to receive'
```

is shown but when I run the client part,

```
line 6, in <module>
clientSocket.connect((serverName,serverPort))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

is shown